# Get Text from one Acitivity to another Activity

Tags: java, android

I have to activitys, "Main" and "Shop" and i got a variable in "Shop" that i would like to use in my "Main"-Activity, how can i do that?
Thanks for help. I would like to have the intCountValue2 in my "Main" class.
That is my whole Shop code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);

    btnBuyClickMultiplier = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClickMultiplierButton);
    txtMultiplierCounter= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ClickMultiplier);

    btnBuyClickMultiplier.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String CountValue2= txtMultiplierCounter.getText().toString();
            int intCountValue2 = Integer.parseInt(CountValue2);
            intCountValue2++;
            txtMultiplierCounter.setText(String.valueOf(intCountValue2));
        }
    });

    configureBackButton1();
}

private void configureBackButton1() {
    Button BackButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BackButton1);
    BackButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't yet know about local variables vs instance fields, and you will need to learn this in order to solve this problem and in order to progress in your Java/Android coding. Please check out [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html): the main Java tutorial, and check for the section on variables.

Answer (score 1):

The easisest way to do it but not the best is to declare your variable "shop" as public and static like the following:

```
public static String shop;
```

And then you can just call that variable in your Main activity as the following:

```
ShopActivity.shop;
```

Comment: Hello Brank, I have set the "public static String shop;" above my @Override, but if i try to call the Variable, it wont work.

Comment: Oh sry, i think you understood me wrong, i got the Variable  "intCountValue" and i would like to have it in my main class.

Comment: Then you must declare your variable intCountValue as public static int intCountValue; as the class atributtes, so you can take it in the MainActivity class as ShopActivity.intCountValue; For assign value to that variable in your ShopActivity should be as "this.intCountValue = theValue"

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it return any error? Can you give more info so I can help?

Answer (score 1):

Before starting Android Programming, you must have a good knowledge about Object Oriented Programming. However, to solve your problem you may try to use `Getter and Setter method` concept (In this particular case, only getter is needed). To do this in your particular case:

- At first, in your `Shop` class declare a private variable (obviously outside any methods, like- `onCreate()` or so)  like this:

  ```
  private int count;
  ```
- Then, create a public method in `Shop` class like this:

  ```
  public int getCount() { 
      return this.count; 
  }
  ```
- Now, in your `onCreate()` method of `Shop` class, inside the `setOnClickListener` of `btnBuyClickMultiplier`, set the value of `count` to `intCountValue2` like this:

  ```
  btnBuyClickMultiplier.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String CountValue2= txtMultiplierCounter.getText().toString();
          int intCountValue2 = Integer.parseInt(CountValue2);
          intCountValue2++;
          txtMultiplierCounter.setText(String.valueOf(intCountValue2));
          count = intCountValue2;
      }
  });
  ```
- Finally, you can access the value of `intCountValue2` variable from the instance of `Shop` class created inside `Main` class like this:

  ```
  Shop s = new Shop();
  int intCountvalue2 = s.getCount();
  ```

Hope you understand.